# How to create a custom module in Qt and use it like Qt += mymodule?

Tags: qt, module, qt5, qwidget

I have created some custom widgets which I can use in my projects by directly using source files or by compiling them to libraries and then using them in my project but I am wondering if I can make a module `MyWidgets` and use it like `Qt += mywidgets`, is it even possible? if yes how can I make one? 
I have searched the internet for a full day but I did not find any step by step guide showing how to make a custom module.
I have found [this article](https://wiki.qt.io/Creating_a_new_module_or_tool_for_Qt) but it doesn't show how to actually make a sample module and build it.